# Creating 20 Related Table for Dynamic Data or Better Solution - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am looking for better solution for my below requirement.

I have to store user's favorite thing like -

> 1. Movies
>
>    1. Name
>    2. Type   // Like sci-fi, thriller, comedy, romantic
>    3. URL [ If any ]
> 2. Music
>
>    1. Name
>    2. Type
>    3. URL [ If any ]
> 3. Cuisine
>
>    1. Name
>    2. Type
>    3. URL [ If any ]
> 4. Sports
>
>    1. Name
>    2. Type
>    3. URL [ If any ]

etc.,

This favorite list can grow more & For each Favorite.

These above columns will be for each favorite items. My Current solutions is creating Table for each favorite thing, like [Favorite movies, Favorite Sports, etc.]. But as these favorite items may increase, and i don't want to create another table for that again from MySQL.

So, I am looking for solution like , Creating table with name just, "favorite", with column :-

> 1. Name.
> 2. Page Link.
> 3. Type.

Those name can be "movies", "books" etc., And inside each "movie" or "books", There will be all data. And Those data will be linked to different user.

So, I need help in Desgining Schema of Table with Relation, by creating less table.

Programming Language, I am using :-

1. MySQL for Database/
2. PHP for Server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a master table `tbl_favoritemaster` to store list of favorite items (e.g. Movies, Books etc...) and with child table `tbl_favoritedetail` to store user's favorite thing (e.g. User wise movie details, User wise books details etc...). Using this structure you are not required to create more tables for all favorite item list.

**1. tbl_favoritemaster**

```
Column List: favoriteId (PK), favoriteName
Data: 

| favoriteId | favoriteName |
|      1     | Movie        |
|      2     | Book         |
```

**2. tbl_favoritedetail**

```
Column List: Id (PK), favoriteId (Reference to tbl_favoritesmaster), Name, Type, URL
Data: 

| Id | favoriteId | Name | Type | URL  |
|  1 |    1       | M1   |  T1  | URL1 |
|  1 |    2       | B1   |  T2  | URL2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that I would approach this.

```
______________________________________________________________
| UniqueID | FavouriteID | Data | Name    | Page Link | Type |
| Int(11)  | Int(11)     | Blob | varchar | Varchar   | Int? |
______________________________________________________________
```

Second table

```
___________________________
| UniqueID | FavouritName |
| INT(11)  | VarChar      |
___________________________
```

Create a foreign key between Table 2 UniqueID and Table 1 FavouritID

when accessing via PHP I use this set of functions myself

```
function RDataLink($field, $table, $current=""){
accessDB();
    $QTable=mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $table");
    $Table=mysql_result($QTable,0,1);
exitDB();
// CONSTRAINT `jobSeeker_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`location`) REFERENCES `24_location` (`UID`)
$x=preg_match_all('/FOREIGN[^(]+.[^(]+[^)]+./',$Table,$matches);
foreach ($matches as $array){
    foreach ($array as $value){
        if(preg_match("/(?<=FOREIGN\sKEY.{3})$field/",$value)){
            if (preg_match("/(?<=REFERENCES[^`].)[^`]+/",$value,$ForeignTable)){
                accessDB();
                    $Qrows=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$ForeignTable[0]);
                exitDB();
                $options="<select name=\"$field\">";
                while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($Qrows,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                    $options.="<option value=\"".$rows['UID']."\"".($current==$rows['UID'] ? "selected" : "") .">".$rows['name']."</option>";
                }
                $options.="</select>";
            }
        }
    }
}
if(!$x){
    return false;
}
    else {
    return $options;
}
}

function RQuery($field,$table,$current){
accessDB();
    $QTable=mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $table");
    $Table=mysql_result($QTable,0,1);
exitDB();
$x=preg_match_all('/FOREIGN[^(]+.[^(]+[^)]+./',$Table,$matches);
foreach ($matches as $array){
    foreach ($array as $value){
        if(preg_match("/(?<=FOREIGN\sKEY.{3})$field/",$value)){
            if (preg_match("/(?<=REFERENCES[^`].)[^`]+/",$value,$ForeignTable)){
                accessDB();
                    $Qrow=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM ".$ForeignTable[0]." WHERE UID='$current'");
                    return mysql_result($Qrow,0);
                exitDB();
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

May take some looking at to apply to your situation. but I hope it is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Since Movies, Music... may have different properties, having a base table for favorable entities may serve:
[image]